# iCarousel Linear Type starts from center

Tags: ios, xcode, icarousel

I would like iCarousel to start appearing from left i.e it should be left aligned. I have found that in case of Linear Carousel it starts from center of the screen.

How can I make the Linear Carousel to start from left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, I was helped by the use of the method `[self.vwCoverFlow scrollToItemAtIndex:2 animated:YES];` in my viewDidLoad.

Comment: But this scroll the carousel at 2nd index not showing first item from extreme left?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a linear scrolling , you can use swipeView class , it is from the same developer as iCarousel but for linear scrolling only . I have used it and it do support left alignment .
Its easy to add and used, same as iCarousel

here is the link for the code https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

Answer (score 1):

Set the wrap property to YES and return the number of placeholderinCarousel as 2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and do it with following hack ;)

**Problem:** 
I need to have view that display only 3 items that are always left aligned.

**Resolution:**
What I have done is to always make at least 3 items. If I have 0, 1 or 2 items I'm always creating 3, but those that do not need to be shown I'm creating as empty UIView. I always have 2 placeholders, but in some cases one or both  are empty.

e.g.
If we have 2 items to display, I'm actually creating three, but third one is empty UIView. I'm creating two placeholders and one Item.

- First item is first *placeholder* at index 0
- Second item is *Item*
- Third item is second *placeholder* but with empty UIView

If we have 1 items to display, again I'm creating three, but second and third one are empty UIView. Same as in previous example, I'm creating two placeholders and one Item.

- First item is first *placeholder* at index 0
- Second item is *Item* but with empty UIView
- Third item is second *placeholder* but with empty UIView

Because of this logic I'm always cleaning view when reusing ([v removeFromSuperview]), to be sure it is clean and if new one needs to be displayed I'm adding it ([view addSubview...). Same logic for *Item* and *Placeholder*

If you need to have more than 3 displayed items you can use same logic, but change value 3 to something else. If I'm wrong update me ;)

Here is a part of mine code that works for me ;)

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [[self getRecordings] count] > 3? [[self getRecordings] count] - 2: 1;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
        // If reusing remove content from holder view for fake items
        for (UIView *v in view.subviews)
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if ([[self getRecordings] count] >= 2)
    {
        [view addSubview:[(RecordingItemViewController*)[_recordingItemViewControllers objectAtIndex:index + 1] view]];
    }

    return view;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 2;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
    // If reusing remove content from holder view for fake items
        for (UIView *v in view.subviews)
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if (([[self getRecordings] count] > 0 && [[self getRecordings] count] < 3 && index == 0) || [[self getRecordings]count] >= 3)
    {
        [view addSubview:[(RecordingItemViewController*)(index == 0? [_recordingItemViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]: [_recordingItemViewControllers lastObject]) view]];
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
    - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel{

       [carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:photosArray.count/2 animated:YES];

        return [photosArray count];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, i would like to suggest using 2 placeholder.

Ex: you have n photos, then you will have (n-2) items and 2 placeholders.
   - Index of items is from 1 to (n-2).
   - Index of placeholders is 0 and (n-1).
Now we will have some code like this:

```
#pragma mark iCarousel DataSource

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //if we have n photos, then number of items is (n-2)
    int count = _movieGalleries.count;
    return count >= 3 ? count - 2 : count;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //2 placeholder
    return _movieGalleries.count >= 3 ? 2 : 0;
}

#pragma mark iCarousel Delegate
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{ 
   //reuse your view
   UIView *yourview = ...

    //get your data
    //index of item is 1 -> n-2, index of placeholder is 0 and n-1
    Item *item = [_listItems objectAtIndex:index + 1];

    //config your view
    ...
    return yourView;
}

- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //index of placeholder is 0 and n-1
    //Trick: we use viewForItemAtIndex for getting placeholder view
    index = index == 0 ? - 1 : carousel.numberOfItems;
    return [self carousel:carousel viewForItemAtIndex:index reusingView:view];
}

- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{

    //in carousel with placeholder, index of selected item is -1, 0, 1, ..., (n-2). which -1 and (n-2) is index of placeholders. So that we need to increase index by 1
    NSLog("current index: %i", index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5:**

Solution that worked for me: Making carousel width double the screen width and constraining carousel to XAnchor of the screen, later adding `contentOffset` that is of 0.5 x size of carousel width. It is also important to present carousel in some `containerView: UIView` and not directly on `viewController` This works because carousel's first item is centered to the center of carousel. If you make carousel double the size of your view and set the `contentOffset` to the left (- 0.5 x size of carousel), the center would be at the left side of your view. Here is some example code:

setting carousel size:

```
carousel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
carousel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
carousel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
carousel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2).isActive = true
carousel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
carousel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

setting carousel contentOffset:

```
carousel.contentOffset = CGSize(width: - containerView.frame.size.width, height: 0)
```

setting property `scrollToItemBoundry` , so that your carousel items will not go out of your reach when you scroll heavily to right:

```
carousel.scrollToItemBoundary = true
```

later on you add your `containerView` to your `viewController.view`:

```
viewController.view.addSubView(containerView)
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```